# KeyError: 'other' when there is no field named 'other' in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a python script to merge two csv files shown below, the variable 'countries' is a dictionary with about 9 countries and data structure is like this:

```
{'FR': {'country_destination': 'FR', 'destination_language ': 'fra', 'lng_destination': '2.209667', 'language_levenshtein_distance': '92.06', 'destination_km2': '643801.0', 'distance_km': '7682.945', 'lat_destination': '46.232193'}, 'NL': {'country_destination': 'NL', 'destination_language ': 'nld', 'lng_destination': '5.29525', 'language_levenshtein_distance': '63.22', 'destination_km2': '41543.0', 'distance_km': '7524.3203', 'lat_destination': '52.133057'}
```

Now this part of code:

```
else:
            correctedRow['destination_language'] = countries[country].get('destination_language', 'NDF') 
            correctedRow['lng_destination'] = countries[country].get('lng_destination', 'NDF')
            correctedRow['language_levanshtien_distance'] = countries[country].get('language_levanshtien_distance', 'NDF')
            correctedRow['destination_km2'] = countries[country].get('destination_km2', 'NDF')
```

is giving me following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f3b0363bcc74> in <module>()
     26                 correctedRow['lat_destination'] = 'NDF'
     27             else:
---> 28                 correctedRow['destination_language'] = countries[country].get('destination_language', 'NDF')
     29                 correctedRow['lng_destination'] = countries[country].get('lng_destination', 'NDF')
     30                 correctedRow['language_levanshtien_distance'] = countries[country].get('language_levanshtien_distance', 'NDF')

KeyError: 'other'
```

Typically key error occurs when the key value I'm trying to access in a python dictionary is missing, which is why I used .get(keyvalue, default) in my code. But I do not understand what is happening here. Can anyone explain? and how should I rectify this?

Comment: `'destination_language '` has a trailing space. You're looking in the dictionary for `'destination_language'` (without a trailing space), which results in the key error.

Comment: hmm...that was embarrassing...okay thank you. But can you explain why the error is 'KeyError: 'other' and not KeyError: 'destination_language' ? This is what threw me off in the first place...

Comment: I added trailing space, I'm getting the same error....

Comment: No problem. I don't see 'other' anywhere in your code (except in the KeyError line). Without seeing the code in full, it's difficult to see if I can reproduce the behaviour (and debug from there). Are you able to post a minimal working example?

Comment: Seems most likely that the error is from looking up `countries[country]`, not the subsequent `get` call. Psychic debugging says `country` is `"other"`, and it isn't find that key in `countries`.

Comment: Where does `country` comes from ? I think that's were "other" is.

Comment: Completely unrelated but it's "lev*e*nsht*ei*n", not "lev*a*nsht*ie*n"

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think you can post your comment as an answer as it's obviously the only way one could get this error here (unless the `dict` is not a proper `dict` but some strange half-backed mapping type of course).

Comment: @ShadoRanger yes you are right, its occuring because one of the countries is 'other', but can you explain what should I do to prevent this?  The reason why I'm using .get(key, default) is to return default when the key is absent right? I should'nt get this error in the first place...and you can post that as answer along with explanation...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems most likely that the error is from looking up `countries[country]`, not the subsequent `get` call. Psychic debugging says `country` is `"other"`, and it isn't finding that key in `countries`.

Your comment asks "The reason why I'm using .get(key, default) is to return default when the key is absent right?" And to that, the answer is, no, you're doing a two stage lookup, first in a `dict` of `dict`s, and the second in the resulting `dict` returned from the first stage. `.get` is saving you from failure in the second stage of the lookup, but it can't magically save you from failure in the first stage if you don't use it for the first stage.

If the goal is to autovivify a country if it doesn't exist, you can do that by changing `countries[country]` to `countries.get(country, {})` so you use `.get` at both stages, and the effect of a non-existent country is to get the default values. Or you can use `countries.setdefault(country, {})` which acts like `get` except it will set the key to the default value given before returning it when the key is not present.

For performance (avoiding redundant lookups and redundant default `dict` construction), you might change the block of code to:

```
country_data = countries.get(country, {})
correctedRow['destination_language'] = country_data.get('destination_language', 'NDF') 
correctedRow['lng_destination'] = country_data.get('lng_destination', 'NDF')
correctedRow['language_levanshtien_distance'] = country_data.get('language_levanshtien_distance', 'NDF')
correctedRow['destination_km2'] = country_data.get('destination_km2', 'NDF')
```